# Upload Image in Vue Component with Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am making a simple website that has a feature to upload images. I tried it Laravel way which I made it in blade template and it works fine. Now I am trying to make it inside Vue Components

Here's my **Create.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>

  <div class="row">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="detail-container">
    <label for="title">Book Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" v-model="book_title" class="form-control">
   </div>
   <div class="detail-container">
    <label for="title">Book Description:</label>
    <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" v-model="book_description" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="detail-container">
    <label for="title">Tags:</label>
    <multiselect v-model="tags" :show-labels="false" name="selected_tags" :hide-selected="true" tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" placeholder="Search or add a tag" label="name" track-by="id" :options="tagsObject" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="addTag" @input="selectTags">
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="tags"></template>
    </multiselect>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7">
   <!-- BOOK COVER WILL GO HERE -->
   <div class="detail-container">
    <label>Book Cover:</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="book_cover" name="selected_cover" @change="onFileChange">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">After you select your desired cover, it will show the preview of the photo below.</small>
    <div id="preview">
     <img v-if="url" :src="url" height="281" width="180" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail-container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveBook()">Next</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

 // register globally
 Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect)

 export default {
  // OR register locally
  components: { Multiselect },
  data () {
   return {
    csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    url: null,
    selected_cover: null,
    tags: [],
    tagsObject: [],
    selected_tags: [],
    book_title: '',
    book_description: ''
   }
  },
  methods: {
   getTags() {
    let vm = this;
    axios.get('/admin/getTags').then(function(result){
     let data = result.data;
     for(let i in data) {
      vm.tagsObject.push({id: data[i].id, name: data[i].name});
     }
    });
   },
   addTag (newTag) {
    const tag = {
     name: newTag,
     id: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
    }
    this.tagsObject.push(tag);
    this.tags.push(tag);
   },
   selectTags(value) {
    this.selected_tags = value.map(a=>a.id);
   },
   onFileChange(e) {
     const file = e.target.files[0];
     this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
     this.selected_cover = file;
   },
   saveBook() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.selected_cover, this.selected_cover.name)
    console.log(this.selected_cover);
    var book_details = {
     'title': this.book_title,
     'description': this.book_description,
     'book_cover': this.selected_cover,
     'tags': this.selected_tags
    };
    
    axios.post('/admin/saveBook', book_details).then(function(result){
     console.log('done')
    })
   }
  },
  created() {
   this.getTags();
  }
 }
</script>

<!-- New step!
  Add Multiselect CSS. Can be added as a static asset or inside a component. -->
<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

and here's my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

     $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required|min:5',
        'description' => 'required|min:10',
        'book_cover' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:10000'
     ]);
    // File Upload
    if($request->hasFile('book_cover')) {
        $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('book_cover')->getClientOriginalName();
        // GET FILE NAME
        $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // GET EXTENSION
        $extension = $request->file('book_cover')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // File Unique Name
        $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'. time().'.'.$extension;
        $path = $request->file('book_cover')->storeAs('public/book_covers', $fileNameToStore);
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

    $book = new Book;
    $book->title = request('title');
    $book->description = request('description');
    $book->book_cover = $fileNameToStore;
    $book->save();

    $book->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

    return back()->with('success', 'Book Created Successfully!');

}
```

I never touched my controller because this is what I used when I do this feature in Laravel Way but when I save it, the details are being saved but the image is not uploading instead it saves noimage.jpg in the database. Does anyone know what  I am doing wrong?

i tried to add this part `const fd = new FormData();` in `book_details` but when i `console.log(fd)` it returned no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass the fd object and not the book_details in your POST request.

you could do it something like this.

```
onFileChange(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    // this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    this.selected_cover = file;
},
saveBook() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.selected_cover)
    fd.append('title', this.book_title)
    fd.append('description', this.book_description)
    fd.append('book_cover', URL.createObjectURL(this.selected_cover))
    fd.append('tags', this.selected_tags)

    axios.post('/admin/saveBook', fd).then(function(result){
        console.log('done')
    })
}
```

and also, you can't just `console.log` the fd in the console. what you can do instead is something like this

```
for (var pair of fd.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

> FormData is a special type of object which is not stringifyable and cannot just be printed out using console.log. ([link](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8125#issuecomment-265514682))

Comment: do I have to change anything in my controller?

Comment: This solved my problem about the file upload but there's another error occured. I got an error in my `this.selected_tags` and it says "SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'tag_id' at